# Generating circle along random position on an arc

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo, generative-art

I'm attempting to get this randomly generated solar system code to display 'planets' randomly along the orbit arc. I'm struggling to find/use the right formula here (see picture for reference of what looks like now).

`draw_orbit(cr, 4, width/2, sun_center, height - next_center - border_size, .6, .6, .6)` is the code for the orbit arc with `height - next_center - border_size` being the radius of the arc.

Current array of points on circle... but formula is wrong and I can't seem to get it:

```
def points_on_circum(r,n=100):
     points_positive = []
     for x in range(0, n + 1):
         xcoord = (math.cos(2 * math.pi / n * x) * r)
         ycoord = (math.sin(2 * math.pi / n * x) * r)
         if xcoord > 0 and ycoord > 0:
             points_positive.append((xcoord, ycoord))
     return points_positive
```

Current thought of how to get the random x, y coordinates of placement:

```
arc = height - next_center - border_size
placement = random.choice(points_on_circum(arc))
         
draw_circle_fill(cr, placement[0],placement[1], next_size, r, g, b)
```

Orbit function:

```
def draw_orbit(cr, line, x, y, radius, r, g, b):
    cr.set_line_width(line)
    cr.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2*math.pi)
    cr.stroke()
```

I'm trying to randomly generate the planets along the arc, but currently they are all at the same position:

[image]

Comment: @mkrieger1 im attempting to get the planets to generate randomly around the smaller line arcs, but within their 'orbits' 

currently, they are all in one line. the `points_on_circum` function isn't firing in this example because it plots them randomly out of sync all over the place

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. If I copy the `points_on_circum` function and call it like `random.choice(points_on_circum(1))`, I do get different coordinates each time, that are not aligned on the `x = 0` axis. Please show a complete [mre].